# Remove elements from original list after filtering

Tags: java, java-8

For example, in C# I can select elements from original list:

```
List<string> result = first_mas.Where(d => d == "1").First().ToList();
```

And if I remove elements from `result`, same elements also will be removed from `first_mas`.

In Java I can do something like this:

```
List<String> result = first_mas.stream().filter(d -> d.equals("1")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But if I remove elements from `result` they will not be removed from original array.

Is it possible to remove elements from original list after filtering?

**UPD:**

```
public void doSomething(List<String> list){
    // here remove something from list, should also be removed from original list
    // i don't have link to original list here
}

doSomething(first_mas.stream().filter(d -> d.get(0).equals("1")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: If you don't have access to the original list, there is no way you could remove/access elements of it.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you expand with a sample input / output? Could you also expand on your use-case?

Comment: I don't see a way using Java8 streams. I do know that collection utilities of Google Guava can perform such things : the Collections.filter utility methods provide "live views" of the original list, and modifications propagate back to the original list. It's not the same, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
List<String> original;
original.removeAll(result);
```

When you get the result, then you can easily remove all the elements which are in the result `List`

Comment: I've updated my question. I don't have link to original array in the method where I remove elements from filtered list.

Comment: I understand your question, but in Java it is not allowed to modify the `List`, The easiest way is to call the `removeAll()` on the original list. It it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably I do not understand well your question, but why can't you pass the list to `doSomething` and then manipulate it with Lambdas?

Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
    l.add("a");
    l.add("b");
    System.out.println(l.size());
    doSomething(l);
    System.out.println(l.size());
}

private static void doSomething(List<String> l) {
    l.stream().filter(s -> s.equals("a")).findFirst().map(l::remove);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`Collection.removeIf(predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method.

According to the docs:

> Removes all of the elements of this collection that satisfy the given predicate.

In your example:

```
first_mas.removeIf(d -> d.equals("1"));
```

Or better:

```
first_mas.removeIf("1"::equals);
```

In case you do need to do this inside the `doSomething(List<String> list)` method, just pass the original list as an argument.